# Why can't users with less than 10 reputation points add images while asking question?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, images

Why can't users with less than 10 reputation points add images while asking question?

What are the alternative ways to include an image with a post from a new user?

Comment: Just link to it?

Comment: Probably because otherwise spammers would post image spam.

Comment: And pornography... on a site that many people use at work.

Comment: @Raedwald Okay But after user getting 10 reputation means they can share any image right? that time spam is not appear?

Comment: What exactly is the feature-request? Do you want to remove the 10-rep barrier or do you want to lower it to say 5-rep?

Comment: No i want to use this Image add feature for all user. because for beginners will explain the issue using Image. so only i asked @InfiniteRecursion

Comment: It takes effort to get those first 10 points. That effort needs to be spent on each and every throw-away account that the troll/spammer makes.

Comment: @Mysticial Okay I understood. My Request is, If i am beginner for stack overflow  I have got problem in my Program i Need to explain problem using Some image what i can do? I just asked that problem only. Sorry to ask anything wrong

Comment: It's fast enough to earn those points. Also, if the question is any good and the image really helps, there are enough people who will be ready to edit the post immediately. Anyway, that barrier seems often not high enough to stop code-as-image posts.

Comment: I don't quite understand the response you're receiving, this is a perfectly valid and logical question.

Comment: @TimPost: Probably because many people on meta cannotget understand they should only vote on [meta-tag:feature-request]s according to (dis-)agreement.

Comment: @Mysticial Out of interest, have there actually been any instances of people posting pornographic images in their questions/answers? I'd guess there probably has been at some point, but I'd also guess that it's a pretty rare occurrence.

Comment: @JonK I've seen it in chat a number of times, but not on the main site - probably because they get moderated very quickly.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This question is probably more interesting than you realized when you asked it. About a year ago, we looked at every *single* image that was blocked due to this restriction (we log each  incident), and the results were interesting:

- 99% of everything blocked was benign, just screen shots, diagrams - what you'd expect.
- The 1% that wasn't benign was *really* awful.

We then took a look at the stuff that was 'normal' (in a sense that it wasn't porn, Hitler, Hitler porn, or the like). About a third of it was:

- A screen shot of someone's code in their IDE instead of code being put in the question and formatted
- A photocopy or picture of a text book or assignment
- A picture of a broken web site, with little to no other text accompanying it

While it's labeled to prevent abuse, it has the added side effect of helping *quite a few* people have a better initial experience on the site by insisting that which should be text is actually text, and that at least a *modicum* of effort is put into explaining the problem. Yes, people can still ask bad questions, but this puts the brakes on several really *bad* categories of them.

You can link to, or provide the URL for any *supplementary* information, photos, diagrams, screen shots, etc - but the keyword there is *supplementary*. If it weren't for the restriction, folks would be a bit more inclined to get that wrong, and much more likely to have a miserable experience subsequently.

In short, we examined the possibility of loosening or removing the restriction, but found that doing so wouldn't be a very good idea - just for reasons quite different than we anticipated :)

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown (and the confirmation that it stops many bad questions with code-as-image and the like). It's a shame there's no way to stop all of them without unacceptably many false positives though...

Comment: On the other hand, the reason why there's so little porn is that trolls will discover that 10-rep barrier on the first try and never try again. If you lift the restriction, they'll try once, realize that it works, and keep doing it over and over.

Comment: Looking at the actual stuff that was blocked was quite surprising, we expected it to be a bit more 'saucy' than it was. Another case of us accidentally getting something right, I'd say.

Comment: Do you realize that people trying to help are having a hard time looking at the content of several links (some questions have more than two) instead of having all the information needed in a single page? This makes life harder for people trying to help and makes the question not self-contained.

Comment: @DavidLeal I have not worked here in a very long time - you'd really need to direct this at someone who does, or the only two people that know your comment is here would remain you and I.

Comment: @TimPost I just wanted to share my opinion from usability perspective about your answer. If we have a spam issue with new contributors, better to attack this with specific user, instead of putting a constraint that affect usability of all questions from such subset of users.

Comment: The other good side effect is that we editors gain a lot of 2 points editing ;)

Answer (score 18):

They can now. We've implemented a change that will [convert images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/426671) to links if a user with less than 10 (or the [new user privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)) attempts to post an image.

They will also be given a gentle warning that says:

[image]

#### Related:

- [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)
- [Warn new users earlier that they cannot post links or images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129833/warn-new-users-earlier-that-they-cannot-post-links-or-images)

Comment: Very nice! I've said quite a few times something along *"just paste the URL of your image into your post, if it's helpful then another user will take care of embedding it"*. Now there's one less thing to explain to newcomers. :-)

Answer (score 10):

> Why can't users with less than 10 reputation points add images while asking question?

As per the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user), these restrictions are placed to prevent new users from spamming the site.

> What are the alternative ways to include an image with a post from a new user?

New users can upload the image and mention the image URL in the post.
Other users who have the required privilege to post images [will come along and post it as an image.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25258259/revisions)