# What causes new contributors to miss the last line in a code block and paste the image as a hyperlink?

Tags: discussion, new-users, formatting

I very often see new contributors asking questions like this:

> ```
> function foo(){
>   return "bar";
> ```
>
> }
>
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atA7X.png)

I personally don't know how they get there, especially for the image one. But since this happens very consistently, is there possibly a design flaw in the SO post editor UI leading new users to create such posts?

Comment: I find it more often they'd miss out the first line. Most likely because they copy/paste from a file where everything is already indented but don't copy the leading whitespace from the first line of code.

Comment: As for the image...it's just the default text when you add an image. The text is prompting you to add your own description. Which the user hasn't done.

Comment: @VLAZ but the editor automatically embed the image when I click "Add Picture". I have to manually delete the leading `[!` and trailing `][1]` around it to make it display like this. How come new users all do this so consistently.

Comment: The embedding is not enabled for new accounts to mitigate possible spam and abuse.

Comment: FWIW, even though most of these can be explained easily, that doesn't mean there isn't a design flaw that can – perhaps – be fixed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi perhaps the new post WYSIWYG editor. I'm not sure what else would help, given that evidently users either don't look at the preview or don't bother to fix it.

Comment: I think the code appearance issue comes from them copying some code that isn't indented enough, pasting, submitting, seeing that the first line is non-monospace because it isn't indented  enough (but all other lines except the last are) and editing to make the first line appear correct but forgetting the last line. To truly know though, why not ask the next person you see doing it?

Comment: @VLAZ I don't have a solution either, and I totally agree that ultimately the issue is that people just don't care. I'm just hoping that someone who is in a less grumpy mood than me isn't put off from answering because there's an impression that "it's obvious and won't matter" or such.

Comment: I think more of the help given for code formatting should be changed to instruct users to use the triple backtick. That would be harder to mess up than the indent.

Comment: @BSMP Good point. Why don't `Ctrl+K` add triple backticks instead of indent? I remember when I wrote my first post, I found `Ctrl+K` quite confusing to use and I didn't know triple backticks was a thing because `Ctrl+K` (and also pressing the `{}` button) leaded me straight to indentation.

Comment: @RickyMo I think it does the indentation because....it was never changed. The triple backtick is a more recent addition, indentation for code was in place since much longer.

Comment: There is a FR to change the default: [Change the code block button from inserting indentation to triple-backticks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414860). No response to that but there is a link to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354572) where it says they won't change it basically because they are working on a new editor.

Comment: I see. I was suspecting my memory of not knowing the triple backticks. Turns out that my memory was correct, it didn't exist back then.

Comment: There is [a change list for these sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange). I don't know if this change is included or not. The list goes back to October 2009.

Comment: @BSMP FWIW, [the blockquote button doesn't work with code fences](/q/386719/4518341), which is to say, they're not perfect.

Comment: Mistakes with markup can happen, BUT... isn't there a live preview right below the edit box, allowing the user to proof-read their post as many times as necessary? Isn't there the feature to edit the question even after it was posted (allowing for further proof-reading and potential corrections? (I've never asked a question, but when I tried it now, the button seemed to say "Review your question", so I presume there's yet another stage allowing for corrections in the process). With all that, why do we still end up with so many malformed questions? Is that really a design issue or does PEBKAC?

Comment: @DanMašek Most noob formatting errors are local optima of correctness. To correct the formatting, you have to first break it. (Meaning you have to know what you're working towards, meaning you have to know Markdown syntax.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't users with less than 10 reputation points add images while asking question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques)

Comment: If you click the _code sample_ button, **then** paste your code, only the first line will have the code formatting indent. Since most often the code is a function/method, its body is already indented, so as the result it will be formatted as code, although at the same level as the first line. The closing brace has no indent, so it does not get formatted like that.

Comment: Note that the new editor, that is already in place on meta, does not have the issue since it uses fenced coded blocks already.

Comment: @DidierL: Are you sure, or is there some kind of opt-in for the new editor?  In the textbox at the bottom of this page, ctrl+k or the `{}` button both indent.  Same on a meta.stackexchange.com post.  (I'm using Chromium on Linux, in case that matters.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4: You don't have to know markdown syntax; there's a `{}` code formatting button that works similar to a WYSIWYG word processor.  You just have to care enough to not crap on the lawn of the people you're asking for help, i.e. review your question and maybe take a couple minutes to figure out the editor.  I have near-zero sympathy for people with boring questions who have that little respect for the people who's attention they're taking. I can see not noticing a stray `}` after doing what you describe in your answer, but fubared ugly indenting or total lack of code format is just rude.

Comment: @PeterCordes indeed, there is a preference for it, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/167668

Comment: @PeterCordes That button's behaviour varies depending on what you've selected. If your selection doesn't include a line break, it puts `inline formatting` in instead of a code block. And you have to know it's there in order to use it: I know it seems obvious to us, but it wasn't obvious for me, seven years ago, when I used my first forum.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: It might be for those reasons, but it could also be explained by the minimum-effort attitude.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: If you look at most other questions or answers as examples, you'll see that formatting is possible.  When I first started using SO, it was after google hits pointed me to existing questions, so I'd already seen how questions should look.  If people haven't done that, and haven't taken the tour, and just dump an ugly post in front of all of us, that's rude, especially if they don't explore any of the many ways they could improve it (e.g. google for "stack overflow format" or something),  It might be unintentional rudeness instead of pure laziness, but I'm still not impressed.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: TL:DR: when starting to participate in a new community, it's partly on the newbie to make an effort to fit in, as well as on the community to make it easy for newbies to figure out how.  You wouldn't wander into a math conference and immediately start bothering people to do your homework, for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand. However, when I first started using the web, that kind of thing was _incomprehensible magic_ to me. It took me a couple of months until I understood that formatting was just instructions given to the computer. Given that _most_ questions are formatted properly, and fixing the formatting doesn't take long (there are those of us who are happy to do it), I don't think it's a very big deal.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I assumed everyone doing programming had heard of HTML and knew that formatting was at least possible.  Thanks for that perspective.  But out of newbie questions, I wouldn't say most of those are formatted properly.  It's not a *big* problem because it's easy to fix with an edit, but it seems to me like the easiest thing for a newbie to have gotten right, easier than tab vs. space breaking indenting when copy/pasting code is an SO quirk. Or realizing what info they need to include for their question to be easily answerable. No formatting still feels like a lack of respect.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Was thinking about this some more: if formatting is the *only* thing wrong with a question, and it's otherwise interesting, and not just another variation on a common problem, that doesn't bother me too much.  But when the question is already poor, like a low-effort code dump or homework dump, that's when bad / no formatting fully solidifies my impression of a lack of respect for the people reading the question, and their time / attention.

Answer (score 22):

I have done both of these. Here's why they happened to me.

### Code blocks

1. Type / paste in the code.
2. Oh, it's not formatted.
3. Move the cursor to the start of the first line.
4. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
5. Hold <kbd>Down</kbd>.
6. Click “Code Sample `<pre><code>` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>”.
7. Post.

Clicking the “Code Sample” button will indent all lines containing selected text. If you've placed the cursor at the very beginning of the first line, you will end up not selecting *any* of the last line, and that last line will not be included in the four-spaces-indented block.

### Image links

1. Upload image.
2. Post.

New users don't have the privileges to post an image, so it gets automatically converted into a hyperlink by the Stack Exchange software. (And if [SmokeDetector](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/) is anything to go by, you should be thankful that the system behaves this way!)

### Related phenomena and speculations

Consider a fictional question:

> Hello, I have a problem with this code :
>
> `#include "stdout.h"`
>
> `int main () {`
>
> `printf("Hello world");`
>
> `}`
>
> It works but there is a warning that I dont understand:
> helloWorld.c:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf'

#### Inline code paragraphs

This can be explained by a user doing the following:

- Type / paste in the first line of code.
- Oh, it's not formatted.
- Select the first line, and click on the formatting button at the top.
- Deduce how the formatting works, adding backticks and paragraph breaks as appropriate.

or:

- Type the start of the question.
- Click on the code icon, to change it to a code font, *without* first pressing Enter.
- See `` `enter code here` ``.
- Paste in the code, breaking the formatting.
- Deduce how the formatting works, adding backticks and paragraph breaks as appropriate to fix it.

#### Unformatted error message

The error message is not in a code block. This is because it is not code; it is an error message. (The asker hasn't noticed that error messages often contain ASCII art, and hasn't realised that errors should *always be posted in monospace*.)

Comment: But why did (past) you not also select the last line before pressing Ctrl+K? You just had to press Down Arrow one more time. I didn't understand why you say the last line isn't selected *because* you made sure the beginning of the first line is selected.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Pressing down arrow one more time doesn't work if the code is at the end of the answer, with no new line afterwards. My habit, when I was a frequent Stack Overflow answerer, was to select the code, go down to the last line, and then press End to select to the end of that line. (I say _because_, because the “select all the lines” procedure that I find intuitive _does_ work if I'm less neat about it.)

Comment: Okay, being the last line of the text box, it makes sense.

Comment: Is that an operating specific thing? I just tried it on Mac and it does indeed select the last line as well even if there is no trailing line break.

Comment: @Clashsoft It's probably OS-specific, yeah. (That would explain why I have muscle-memory for doing it wrong.)

Comment: And then there is the annoying bug with doing a numeration or bullet point style list with a code block following where the code block is not picked up correctly.

Comment: @Clashsoft: Or perhaps a browser thing?  Chromium on GNU/Linux does allow you to shift+down_arrow on the last line to select it; tested just now.  Of course if I actually wanted to select from a certain point to the end of the textbox, I'd ctrl+shift+end, which also works, and I assume works portably even in cases where shift+down wouldn't select the contents of the last line.

Comment: Re *"...Down"*: Do you mean the [down arrow key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_keys)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I do.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen a number of posts where the code snippet just seems to be pasted in. *Most* of the snippet *happens* to already be indented with 4 spaces, so it gets formatted. There are dangling brackets or the code isn't consistently indented, so a few hang out. My impression that new users don't plan on formatting their code to begin with, and are probably surprised/confused when part of the code does get formatted, but don't know/care to fix it the part that isn't.

With regards to images, I figured it was the same thing, but when I tried it, I discovered that pasting a picture results in this markdown:

`[![enter image description here][1]][1]`

I don't remember this always being the case but it's likely that it's just what [wizzwizz4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5223757/wizzwizz4) said about images.