# How to paste Python code in Stack Overflow without DIY

Tags: support, code-formatting

Here is an image of correct code (in fact, code of [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73335945/3001761)):

[image: Screen image]

If I copy this code and paste it in a code sample in this editor, I got this (another image):

[image: Screen copy of Stack Overflow result]

So I'm obliged to add a tab at the beginning of the whole code (this is not valid Python code any more as can be seen by the red line under *def*):

[image]

Then, if I paste into a code sample, I obtain the following which is not yet correct as the first line is indented twice (and we don’t have any syntax colors):

```
    # original code with right indentation
def animals(ani1, ani2, ani3):
    if ani1 == ani2 or ani1 == ani3:
        return "Match was Found"
    elif ani2 == ani1 or ani2 == ani3:
        return "Match was Found"
    elif ani3 == ani2 or ani3 == ani1:
        return "Match was Found"
    else:
        return "No Match Found"
print(animals("dogs", "dogs", "cats"))
```

So I'm obliged to correct by hand to have a final result as expected:

```
# original code with right indentation
def animals(ani1, ani2, ani3):
    if ani1 == ani2 or ani1 == ani3:
        return "Match was Found"
    elif ani2 == ani1 or ani2 == ani3:
        return "Match was Found"
    elif ani3 == ani2 or ani3 == ani1:
        return "Match was Found"
    else:
        return "No Match Found"
print(animals("dogs", "dogs", "cats"))
```

Then I go back to my editor (Visual Studio Code) to restore the correct indentation.

What is the best way to paste Python code directly without all this stuff?

Comment: Paste the code, select it, then press the 'Code sample' button `{}` or Ctrl-K ?

Comment: my question will be soon blocked by administrators as not useful etc. I take time to redact precisely the case and i'm not probably the unique guy that see 'code icon' in the editor and think this must work seeing 'paste code here' . Thanks to those who responded.

Comment: I don't really get what your problem is. Did you press the code sample button *before* pasting your code? There is no reference in your question to pressing this button.

Comment: yes, i press the code sample and see 'paste your code here', what i do with explained defects.  By the way, thank you for not tossing my question like an old rag :)

Comment: Well, I had never tried to press it before, but I find the behaviour in this case misleading, and problematic regarding indentation. Maybe it would be better if it did nothing in this case...

Comment: Pressing the button first is designed for the case where you are going to immediately thereafter type in a single line of code. It's not meant for when you are going to copy-paste in a block of code. For what it's worth, we did recently have a discussion about this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419468/why-does-the-first-line-of-a-code-block-often-get-an-extra-level-of-indentation @ThierryLathuille

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always use three backticks (```) and prevent the need to indent the code:

````
```
code
```
````

Or select and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to indent automatically.

Comment: What kind of grinds my gears is that this is explained in the [documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... but you have to click a very small print "show more" link to see it :/ I'm sorry, but that looks like someone is trying to make it hard to find relevant information. As Reddit would put it, a-hole design.